# What is KendoUI equivalent of angular $location.path

Tags: kendo-ui

I need to replace a url querystring, the part after ?, without refreshing/navigating to a new page.  This is to make my page more seo/book mark friendly.

This functionality is available in angular with $location.path but Kendo does not fully support angular and referencing $location breaks the app navigation.

What is the KendoUI equivalent of $location.path?

Answer (score 0):

I went with this solution that seems to work.

```
$timeout(function () {
    window.history.replaceState({ 
        path: newurl 
    }, '', newurl);
}, 500);
```